# How to insert a list as a column in a 2D-list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

Given a list and a 2d-list (that may or may not be the same length)

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]

list2 = [1,2]

table = [[1,2,0],
         [3,4,1],
         [4,4,4]]
```

I want to append the list as a column to the 2d-list, managing the empty values adequately.

```
result1 = [[1,2,0,         1],
           [3,4,1,         2],
           [4,4,4,         3],
           [None,None,None,4]]

result2 = [[1,2,0,   1],
           [3,4,1,   2],
           [4,4,4,None]]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
table = [column + [list1[0]] for column in table]
```

But I'm having syntax problems using an iterator in place of the `0`.

I was thinking something like this:

```
table = [column + [list1[i]] for column in enumerate(table,i)]
```

But I get a tuple concatenated to tuple `TypeError`. I was thinking that it might be a good idea to pivot the table and then just append a row and pivot back, but I couldn't get that idea to handle the sizing issues appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generator function and [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def add_column(lst, col):

    #create the list col, append None's if the length is less than table's length
    col = col + [None] * (len(lst)- len(col))

    for x, y in izip_longest(lst, col):
        # here the if-condition will run only when items in col are greater than 
        # the length of table list, i.e prepend None's in this case.
        if x is None:
            yield [None] *(len(lst[0])) + [y] 
        else:
            yield x + [y]            


print list(add_column(table, list1))
#[[1, 2, 0, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 4, 4, 3], [None, None, None, 4]]
print list(add_column(table, list2))
#[[1, 2, 0, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 4, 4, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
table = [column + [list1[i] if i < len(list1) else None] for i, column in enumerate(list1)]
```